# Reattach separated range hood duct in attic, without access

Tags: ducts, range

I'm refurbishing a kitchen, and removed all the cabinets to refinish them. The small cabinet above the range has the standard rectangular 10"x3.5" duct going through it to exhaust the fan. Unfortunately in removing that cabinet, I also pulled out the duct section from where it attaches in the attic space, a few feet above the ceiling. It's a crimp joint between the sections, and it pulled out.

Now I have to reattach that section, but I don't have easy access to that part of the attic. It's a very low-pitch roof, and it would be near impossible to shimmy from the access hatch all the way to the kitchen.

If I just shove the section up into the hole, there's no chance of the joint lining up well enough on all four sides so that it can be reconnected.

Is there a good trick for this situation? I can reach an arm up into the hole and grab the upper section, but of course I can't fit the duct and an arm or two at the same time.  I can always embiggen the ceiling hole, but I'd prefer not to make that repair if I can avoid it.

Comment: Normally a roof jack accepts round, not rectangular duct. Is there an adapter from rectangular to round between the roof jack and the square ducting?

You could just eliminate all of the rectangular duct work and replace with round flex duct. Then you could get your hands up there and attach the flex duct with a clamp and tape and pull it back down thru the attic.

Comment: Can you put your arm inside the new section and guide the edges with your hand? If so, you could then seal it with metal tape on the inside.

Comment: Does the vent go out under the roof or above?

Comment: @User95050: It goes out above, to a rooftop vent.